# ¿Cómo puedo restar una cantidad de un campo entre 2 tablas con Trigger?

Tags: mysql, trigger

**Tengo el siguiente TRIGGER MYSQL:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER salidas_A_U AFTER INSERT ON salidas 
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE toners SET cantidad = cantidad - cantidad_s WHERE id_toner = 7
```

Quiero que después de hacer el insert correspondiente a la tabla salidas, actualice la tabla toners en el campo cantidad y le reste la cantidad que salió. CANTIDAD TONERS = CANTIDAD TONERS - CANTIDAD SALIR y se vea reflejado en la cantidad de la tabla toners.

Comment: ¿Y ese trigger qué resultado entrega?

Comment: Ese no me entrega nada pero en cambio, si pongo cantidad = cantidad-1. Solo pues resta esa cantidad (1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En los triggers tu tienes acceso a dos objetos (`old`, `new`)que contienen la estructura de tu tabla.

En este caso lo que tendrias que hacer es tomar de new, que contiene los valores insertados.

```
CREATE TRIGGER salidas_A_U AFTER INSERT ON salidas 
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE toners SET cantidad = cantidad - new.cantidadSalir  WHERE id_toner = 7
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, apenas le estoy entendiendo a los triggers. Si me funcionó